# Mac Cocoa: To differentiate if a NSScrollWheel event is from a mouse or trackpad?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have found this, but how to pass an `NSEvent` object and call this function?

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{      
    if(([theEvent momentumPhase] != NSEventPhaseNone) || [theEvent phase] != NSEventPhaseNone))
    {
      //theEvent is from trackpad           
    }
    else 
    {
       //theEvent is from mouse
     }
}
```

Comment: I have a tableView, how to enable my NSTableView to respond to scroll event?

Comment: Normally a tableView is in and is expected to be in a common NSScrollView hierarchy.